# Loop While condition is TRUE

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am trying to generate n random numbers whose sum is less than 1.

So I can't just run `runif(3)`. But I can condition each iteration on the sum of all values generated up to that point.

The idea is to start an empty vector, `v`, and set up a loop such that for each iteration, `i`, a `runif()` is generated, but before it is accepted as an element of `v`, i.e. `v[i] <- runif()`, the test `sum(v) < 1` is carried out, and while  `FALSE` the last entry `v[i]` is finally accepted, ***BUT*** if `TRUE`, that is the sum is greater than 1, `v[i]` is tossed out of the vector, and the iteration `i` is repeated.

I am far from implementing this idea, but I would like to resolve it along the lines of something similar to what follows. It's not so much a practical problem, but more of an exercise to understand the syntax of loops in general:

```
n <- 4
v <- 0

for (i in 1:n){
    rdom <- runif(1)
    if((sum(v) + rdom) < 1) v[i] <- rdom
    }
    # keep trying before moving on to iteration i + 1???? i <- stays i?????
}
```

I have looked into `while` (actually I incorporated the `while` function in the title); however, I need the vector to have `n` elements, so I get stuck if I try something that basically tells R to add random uniform realizations as elements of the vector `v` `while` `sum(v) < 1`, because I can end up with less than `n` elements in `v`.

Comment: To loop _while_ a condition is true, use `while`....

Comment: What do you want to use as a limit? Number of tries, `sum(v)`,  length of `v`?

Comment: I want to end up with a vector `v` such that the sum of its elements, `sum(v)` does not exceed 1, but I need the vector to have n elements.

Comment: So I can't cook something up with `while (sum(v))` is less than 1, keep adding elements, but the minute it goes over 1, `break`, because I could end up with less than `n` elements in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. <s>It doesn't use `while` but the more generic `repeat`.</s> I edited it to use a `while` and save a couple of lines.

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 4
v <- numeric(n)
i <- 0
while (i < n) {
  ith <- runif(1)
  if (sum(c(v, ith)) < 1) {
    i <- i+1
    v[i] <- ith
  }
}
v
# [1] 0.89669720 0.06178627 0.01339033 0.02333120
```

Using a `repeat` block, you must check for the condition anyways, but, removing the growing problem, it would look very similar:

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 4
v <- numeric(n)
i <- 0
repeat {
  ith <- runif(1)
  if (sum(c(v, ith)) < 1) {
    i <- i+1
    v[i] <- ith
  }
  if (i == 4) break
}
```

Comment: You can go ahead and allocate `numeric(n)` and use another variable, `i` to track the current utilization. The while condition would then be `while(i<n)`.

Comment: @A.Webb Indeed, just did it.

Comment: I like it a lot because it follows the scheme of my beginner's idea. Could you include both models (the one you erased and the final one) , perhaps to contrast one with the other sort of line-by-line?

Comment: @Toni Sure, but tbh it doesn't look much different after I improved it a bit.

Comment: Let me summarize the core idea - get rid of `for(i in ...)` so that you liberate the `i` to *control* it inside `repeat` or `while`, which is not possible with `for`. And, second, condition the end of the process to `i` reaching `n`. Is that a good summary?

Comment: I think one downside with this is that rejection sampling the next element can be very expensive if n is large. For instance I ran the first code block and set `n <- 100` and it's been working a long time on that one sample with no sign of returning.

Comment: @Toni I think yes, it is.

Comment: @josliber Definitely. Your `hitandrun` solution is much more elegant and robust, and no doubt better mathematically. I suppose the only advantage of doing it this way is that it follows the algorithm somewhat easily, but your second solution is somewhere in the middle: not so black-box yet more efficient. You should get the votes and acceptance here. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep exactly the same procedure that you have posted (aka iteratively sample the `n` values one at a time from the standard uniform distribution, rejecting any samples that cause your sum to exceed 1), then the following code is mathematically equivalent, shorter, and more efficient:

```
samp <- function(n) {
  v <- rep(0, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    v[i] <- runif(1, 0, 1-sum(v))
  }
  v
}
```

Basically, this code uses the mathematical fact that if the sum of the vector is currently `sum(v)`, then sampling from the standard uniform distribution until you get a value no greater than `1-sum(v)` is exactly equivalent to sampling in the uniform distribution from 0 to `1-sum(v)`. The advantage of using the latter approach is that it's much more efficient -- we don't need to keep rejecting samples and trying again, and can instead just sample once for each element.

To get a sense of the runtime differences, consider sampling 100 observations with `n=10`, comparing to a working implementation of the code from your post (copied from my other answer to this question):

```
OP <- function(n) {
  v <- rep(0, n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    rdom <- runif(1)
    while (sum(v) + rdom > 1) rdom <- runif(1)
    v[i] <- rdom
  }
  v
}
set.seed(144)
system.time(samples.OP <- replicate(100, OP(10)))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 261.937   1.641 265.805 
system.time(samples.josliber <- replicate(100, samp(10)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.004   0.001   0.004
```

In this case, the new approach is approaching 100,000 times faster.

Comment: Really nice. I wish I could accept both answers. Yours is spectacular in the histogram plots, and the run time analysis. And you gave also a code along the basic loop structure I was asking for...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to uniformly sample from a space of `n` variables where the following constraints hold:

```
x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n <= 1
x_1 >= 0
x_2 >= 0
...
x_n >= 0
```

The ["hit and run" algorithm](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.32.6.1296) is the mathematical machinery that enables you to do exactly this. In 2-dimensional space, the algorithm will sample uniformly from the following triangle, with each location in the shaded area being equally likely to be selected:

[image]

The algorithm is provided in R through the `hitandrun` package, which requires you to specify the linear inequalities that define the space through a constraint matrix, direction vector, and right-hand side vector:

```
library(hitandrun)
n <- 3
constr <- list(constr = rbind(rep(1, n), -diag(n)),
               dir = c(rep("<=", n+1)),
               rhs = c(1, rep(0, n)))
set.seed(144)
samples <- hitandrun(constr, n.samples=1000)
head(samples, 10)
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#  [1,] 0.28914690 0.01620488 0.42663224
#  [2,] 0.65489979 0.28455231 0.00199671
#  [3,] 0.23215115 0.00661661 0.63597912
#  [4,] 0.29644234 0.06398131 0.60707269
#  [5,] 0.58335047 0.13891392 0.06151205
#  [6,] 0.09442808 0.30287832 0.55118290
#  [7,] 0.51462261 0.44094683 0.02641638
#  [8,] 0.38847794 0.15501252 0.31572793
#  [9,] 0.52155055 0.09921046 0.13304728
# [10,] 0.70503030 0.03770875 0.14299089
```

Breaking down this code a bit, we generated the following constraint matrix:

```
constr
# $constr
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]   -1    0    0
# [3,]    0   -1    0
# [4,]    0    0   -1
# 
# $dir
# [1] "<=" "<=" "<=" "<="
# 
# $rhs
# [1] 1 0 0 0
```

Reading across the first line of `constr$constr` we have 1, 1, 1 which indicates "1*x1 + 1*x2 + 1*x3". The first element of `constr$dir` is `<=`, and the first element of `constr$rhs` is `1`; putting it together we have `x1 + x2 + x3 <= 1`. From the second row of `constr$constr` we read -1, 0, 0 which indicates "-1*x1 + 0*x2 + 0*x3". The second element of `constr$dir` is `<=` and the second element of `constr$rhs` is `0`; putting it together we have `-x1 <= 0` which is the same as saying `x1 >= 0`. The similar non-negativity constraints follow in the remaining rows.

Note that the hit and run algorithm has the nice property of having the exact same distribution for each of the variables:

```
hist(samples[,1])
```

[image]

```
hist(samples[,2])
```

[image]

```
hist(samples[,3])
```

[image]

Meanwhile, the distribution of the samples from your procedure will be highly uneven, and as `n` increases this problem will get worse and worse.

```
OP <- function(n) {
  v <- rep(0, n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    rdom <- runif(1)
    while (sum(v) + rdom > 1) rdom <- runif(1)
    v[i] <- rdom
  }
  v
}
samples.OP <- t(replicate(1000, OP(3)))

hist(samples.OP[,1])
```

[image]

```
hist(samples.OP[,2])
```

[image]

```
hist(samples.OP[,3])
```

[image]

An added advantage is that the hit-and-run algorithm appears faster -- I generated these 1000 replicates in 0.006 seconds on my computer with hit-and-run and it took 0.3 seconds using the modified code from the OP.

Comment: @Toni I've added some description of the constraint matrix; I think the important take-away from this answer is that hit-and-run is not giving you the same same as your code but in my opinion is probably solving the problem you actually want to be solving (uniformly sample the space of `n` non-negative variables whose sums do not exceed 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, without any loop, `if` or `while`:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(1) # start with the sum that you want to obtain
n <- 4 # number of generated random numbers, can be chosen arbitrarily 
y <- sort(runif(n-1,0,x)) # choose n-1 random points to cut the range [0:x]
z <- c(y[1],diff(y),x-y[n-1]) # result: determine the length of the segments
#> z
#[1] 0.11761257 0.10908627 0.02723712 0.03364156
#> sum(z)
#[1]  0.2875775
#> all.equal(sum(z),x)
#[1] TRUE
```

The advantage here is that you can determine exactly which sum you want to obtain and how many numbers `n` you want to generate for this. If you set, e.g., `x <- 1` in the second line, the `n` random numbers stored in the vector `z` will add up to one.

Comment: How did you select the target sum here? Is there some reasoning for selecting it uniformly between 0.5 and 1?

Comment: The code will work equally with `x <- runif(1,0,1)`. Possibly that would be a more appropriate choice since the OP did not specify any lower limit.

Comment: OK, just trying to wrap my head around this code -- do all four positions have the same distribution across many samples? I like this solution more than the OP's code and the solution by Molx because it won't take an hour to generate one sample with n=100.

Comment: @josliber The idea is that you take one range, from 0 to, say, 1. Then you divide it into four segments by means of three cutpoints distributed randomly and in a uniform fashion within this range. After that, all you have to do is to calculate the length of these segments. Those are your random numbers, and the sum will be equal to the length of the initial range.